# select latest item query blows up the memory

Tags: influxdb

I have encountered with a surprising issue.

I need to find the time of the latest item in one of my measurements that has < 300k series.
Once i execute 'SELECT * FROM measurement ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1' my memory goes to 99%.

Since the query contains LIMIT 1 this behavior sounds like a bug to me, since it should be very trivial to compute this query.

Is this behavior expected in some way?

Comment: If time is not indexed, all records must be read and sorted.  Make time an index or order by something like record id

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using? With 1.4 you can use `EXPLAIN <query>` and `EXPLAIN ANALYSE <query>` to get some insight about the query plan and runtime costs.

Comment: Unfortunately it is 1.3, maybe I will upgrade in that case

Comment: @DaveS I am kind of new to InfluxDB, I was sure that time is indexed by default. The problem is that tags are really expensive in terms of memory, wouldn't something like record id as tag causes the number of series to possibly be very big?

Comment: @primm it would, and time is indexed by defauly. I think DaveS has maybe mistaken this for an SQL question.